# Callback function invoked in a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, callback, delegates, invoke

```
class Machine
{
  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  delegate int delConnectionCallback(IntPtr caller, int MachineIndex);

  [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  delegate int delDisconnectionCallback(IntPtr caller, int MachineIndex));

  private static void Run()
  {
     // random machine for test purposes
     int machineIndex = 12;

     // Return the memory address of the functions where the callback will happen
     // These will be passed to the MachineDriverDLL class so that the C++ Driver DLL 
     //    knows where to return the call
     IntPtr ptrConnect = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(OnConnCallback);
     IntPtr ptrDisconn = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(OnDiscCallback);

     // map the machine dll object 
     var m = new MachineDriverDll();

     // connect to the machine
     m.Connect(machineIndex, ptrConnect, ptrDisconnect);
  }

  // Connect call from the DLL driver
  private static delConnectionCallback OnConnCallback = (caller, MachineIndex) =>
  {         
     Log(MachineIndex);

     // more long code here

     return 0;
  };

  // Disconnect Call from the DLL driver
  private static delDisconnectionCallback OnDiscCallback = (caller, MachineIndex) =>
  {
     Log(MachineIndex);

     // more long code here

     return 0;
  };
}
```

`OnConnCallback` and `OnDiscCallback` are called from a C++ DLL. How do I structure the code so that the two functions are invoked in separate threads, in an asynchronous manner, without interrupting the `for` loop?

Currently, the `for` loop stops counting when either of the callbacks fire.

Comment: How does your C++ dll know about those?

Comment: Updated the code. See above.

Comment: I have edited your question but I feel it is still vague.  Do you want to have the callbacks be invoked in a separate thread so that the `for` loop is not interrupted? If so, my edit reflects that.  (PS: Please wait for the edit to be approved.)

Comment: @Sabuncu yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is to update this line of code -

```
m.Connect(machineIndex, ptrConnect, ptrDisconnect);
```

to

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => m.Connect(machineIndex, ptrConnect, ptrDisconnect));
```

This way, it starts your C++ code on a separate thread instead of on current running thread. Just make sure that you exit/dispose your C++ code cleanly before you exit your C# code.